# Why is my function outputting different parts of its result at different times?

Tags: haskell, lambda, ghc

Currently I have a function that takes a good deal of time to run, lets call it `somefunction`.  `somefunction` returns a tuple, for simplicity lets say its `(String,Int)`.  I wanted to output the result of this function in a neat fashion, so I wrote the following code (not exactly this code, but for simplicity we'll say it is):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
 putStr$ (\ (a,b) -> a ++ "\ninteger: " ++ (show b) ++ "\n" ) (somefunction args)
```

So I started my code.  After a while it printed the `a` part of the tuple, without the `b`.  After another long period of time it output the `b` portion.

Why is there so much lag before the second part of the tuple is outputted?  What's going on here?

---

In my case `somefunction` is the function `debugbrainflak` in the following code:

```
module Interpreter (debugbrainflak) where

pop :: (Integral a) => [a] -> a
pop [] = 0
pop (x:_) = x

rest :: (Integral a) => [a] -> [a]
rest [] = []
rest (_:x) = x

topadd :: [Integer] -> Integer -> [Integer]
topadd [] x = [x]
topadd (a:[]) x = [a+x]
topadd (a:b) x = (a+x):b

ir :: [Char] -> Integer -> [Char]
ir x 0 = ""
ir ('{':x) y = "{" ++ (ir x (y+1))
ir ('}':x) y = "}" ++ (ir x (y-1))
ir (a:x)   y = [a] ++ (ir x   y  )

interior :: [Char] -> [Char]
interior x = init (ir x 1)

ex :: [Char] -> Integer -> [Char]
ex x 0 = x
ex ('{':x) y = ex x (y+1)
ex ('}':x) y = ex x (y-1)
ex  (a:x)  y = ex x y

exterior :: [Char] -> [Char]
exterior x = ex x 1

---

dbf :: [Char] -> ([Integer],[Integer],[Integer],Int) -> ([Integer],[Integer],[Integer],Int)
dbf []          (x,y,z,c)= (x,y,z,c)
dbf ('(':')':a) (x,y,z,c)= dbf a (x,y,((pop z+1):rest z),c+1)
dbf ('<':'>':a) (x,y,z,c)= dbf a (y,x,z,c+1)
dbf ('{':'}':a) (x,y,z,c)= dbf a ((rest x),y,(topadd z (pop x)),c+1)
dbf ('[':']':a) (x,y,z,c)= dbf a (x,y,(topadd z (toInteger (length x))),c+1)
dbf ('(':a)     (x,y,z,c)= dbf a (x,y,(0:z),c+1)
dbf ('<':a)     (x,y,z,c)= dbf a (x,y,(0:z),c+1)
dbf ('[':a)     (x,y,z,c)= dbf a (x,y,(0:z),c+1)
dbf (')':a) (x,y,(h:z),c)= dbf a ((h:x),y,(topadd z h),c+1)
dbf (']':a) (x,y,(h:z),c)= dbf a (x,y,(topadd z (-h)),c+1)
dbf ('>':a) (x,y,(_:z),c)= dbf a (x,y,z,c+1)
dbf ('{':a)      t     = dbf (exterior a) (drun (interior a) t)
dbf (_:a)        t     = dbf a t

drun :: [Char] -> ([Integer],[Integer],[Integer],Int) -> ([Integer],[Integer],[Integer],Int)
drun s ([],y,z,c)  = ([],y,z,c)
drun s (0:x,y,z,c) = (0:x,y,z,c)
drun s x         = drun s (dbf s x)

--

bl :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool
bl [] [] = True
bl [] _  = False
bl ('(':x) y   = bl x (')':y) 
bl ('[':x) y   = bl x (']':y) 
bl ('<':x) y   = bl x ('>':y) 
bl ('{':x) y   = bl x ('}':y) 
bl  (a:x) []
 | elem a ")]>}" = False
 | otherwise     = bl x []
bl (a:x) (b:y)
 | elem a ")]>}" = (a == b) && (bl x y)
 | otherwise     = bl x (b:y)

balanced :: [Char] -> Bool
balanced x = bl x []

clean :: [Char] -> [Char]
clean [] = []
clean ('#':'{':xs) = clean (exterior xs)
clean (x:xs)
 | elem x "()[]<>{}" = x:(clean xs)
 | otherwise         = clean xs

debugbrainflak :: [Char] -> [Integer] -> ([Integer], Int)
debugbrainflak s x
 | balanced s = (\(a,_,_,d) -> (a,d)) (dbf (clean s) (x,[],[],0))
 | otherwise  = error "Unbalanced braces."
```

If you would like a test case that emulates the behavior you can try (you can change how long it takes by increasing or decreasing the number):

```
debugbrainflak "({({}[()])}{})" [999999]
```

Comment: In this case, no: the function is only being called once. Since Haskell is lazy,  it evaluates only by need. It is likely that the two computations returned in the tuple from `somefunction` are more or less independent so that when even after `a` has been evaluated (and `integer` printed) there is still work to do to evaluate `b`.

Comment: @Alec The computation for `b` *requires* `a` to be computed, although the computation for `a` does not require `b` to be computed.  Is there some way I could force haskell to calculate them both at once?

Comment: what @Alec meant is that suppose `somefunction` is defined like this `somefunction args = (somefastfunction args,someslowfunction args)`, then `show a` evaluates `somefastfunction` which is fast but `show b` evaluates `someslowfunction` which is slow, yes friend lazy evaluation can be tricky

Comment: if `b` requires `a` then `a` will be evaluated once then `b` will continue evaluation using the already evaluated `a`, can you show us actual code because without it we can only give you guesses

Comment: @niceman I've added the definition now if it helps.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but a bit more about what's going on here: It looks like your `c` parameter in `dbf` is not being forced, which means that it's building up as a big thunk like `1+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1+(...` and only actually doing the addition when you show it, which takes time if it's large.  The way through this is to make sure that `c` gets evaluated at each recursive step of `dbf`.

With the way you have written it this could be a little awkward.  One way would be to add as the first equation of `dbf`:

```
dbf _ (_,_,_,c) | c `seq` False = undefined
```

which feels like a bit of a hack, but allows you to experiment without changing every line of your interpreter.

In the long run I'd probably define a data type for the state instead of a tuple, and make it a [strict field](https://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/strict-field.xhtml):

```
data InterpState = InterpState {
    stack1 :: [Integer],
    stack2 :: [Integer],
    stack3 :: [Integer],
    instrCount :: !Int
  }
```

Comment: Ok this makes sense.  Would forcing `c` make things faster or even more memory efficient? or would it just cause them to output simultaneously?

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch yes it should improve everything. Needless thunk build up is not good for performance.

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch As an extra approach, you could also enable `BangPatterns` and adjust the patterns to `(x,y,z,!c)`, but I agree with luqui that a data type is the way to go.

Comment: I implemented the data type solution as you had suggested and was surprised to find it made the entire process just over 3 times slower.  Perhaps I am doing something wrong but I think that I will go with Antal's suggestion of `BangPatterns`.

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch, that should not definitely not happen.  If you still have that code may I look?

Comment: Sure, the code can be found [here](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack) in its entirety.  I've implemented the data type on the master branch and the hack on the `dev` branch.  There is an IO wrapper here, but the `Interpreter.hs` is a modified version of the code provided in the original question.  Thanks for your continued concern!

Comment: It turns out that when using compiler optimizations `O2` and `O3` the difference in timing disappears.

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch oh man.  I've heard `-O2` is even too much, but I'm interested in your results.  `-O3` doesn't mean "make it faster", it means "do riskier things which might make the code faster, but could also make it slower", and I've heard `-O` is best.  Though I'm not really a performance junkie so I have little real-world experience of this.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say exactly what's going on without seeing `somefunction`, but in general, GHC¹ is not going to duplicate work like that.  However, since Haskell is lazy, as soon as it has done enough work to generate the start of the string, it will print out *that portion* of the string.  So if you have

```
slow1 :: Args -> String
slow2 :: Args -> Int

somefunction :: Args -> (String, Int)
somefunction args = (slow1 args, slow2 args)
```

Then GHC will start by forcing just `slow1 args`, print that out, print out `"\ninteger: "`, and *then* force `slow2 args`, `show` it, and print it out.  (And then print the trailing `"\n"`.)

You can test this as follows:

```
main :: IO ()
main =
  let (a,b) = somefunction args
  in putStr $ a `seq` b `seq` (a ++ "\ninteger: " ++ show b ++ "\n")
```

Here, `` x `seq` y `` is equal to `y`, but forcing `y` will force *both* `x` and `y` before evaluating to `y`.  This means that `` a `seq` b `seq` ... `` will ensure that `a` and `b` are fully computed before the string containing them is returned.

This code using `seq` should print out everything all at once – but it'll probably wait just as long as your old code did, just all up front instead of in between printing `a` and `show b`.

---

¹ The Haskell Report doesn't specify that sort of detail about evaluation, so I'll be speaking about what GHC in particular does in this answer – which is usually what people are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've added `somefunction` to my question above.  I don't believe that what you are suggesting is what is going on, but its still a possibility.

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch The problem (which luqui highlighted) is essentially the same – note that the solution still involves `seq`.  It's not literally two functions, but it's the same split between calculating one and the other.